# Spam or serious logins? Notifications of desktop recently disconnect on my linux machine

Tags: debian, login, firefox, desktop, laptop

apologies if the question sound silly but I'm a fairly basic user with very little experience. I got a notification on my computer (see picture) that a desktop computer had disconnected from my laptop. I wasn't sure if it's just spam or a serious issue, so I panicked and changed the passwords on my bank accounts, stopped all notifications from firefox, etc.. This morning it happened again so I'm really starting to worry. Is there a way to know if and when somebody logged in? and if they did is there a way to know what they did? Thanks!
[image]

Comment: I found this explanation: [What are these Disconnected notifications in the notification list?](https://askubuntu.com/q/1423740) I hope this will solve your problem. Seems related to Bluetooth...

Comment: Oh gosh, that is exactly the same problem! Thanks soooo much for your help, you're amazing!